# is it possible to take a screenshot from storyboard preview?

Tags: ios, xcode, screenshot, preview

In Xcode 6+ there is an option to preview the storyboard on multiple screen sizes. 
I wonder if there is a way to take screenshots of this preview (for the app screenshot in iTunes connect)?

Comment: Besides running it in your simulator and using Cmd+Shift+4? Or from within the simulator File > Save Screenshot?

Comment: Direct Screenshot from Storyboard is not possible. Preview of storyboard means, you can check your screen with other different size from you are doing UI integration, like of you working with 4-Inch Design, then you can preview it by Preview of Storyboard of other screen like 4.7, 5.5, landscap, portrait, etc.

Comment: Right. I am having hard time simulating a scenario that can be easily produced by editing the storyboard

Answer (score 0):

You should use screenshots from the simulator using command+s or from an real iOS device. I don't know if screen captures from the the Storyboard preview would qualify as "real" screens and it may be rejected during review.